# horizontal scroll bar of IE and input text box

Tags: html, text, input

I have a situation, where I have a text input box in IE(input type='text')
But the horizontal scroll bar of IE will be shown when it has lots of texts , and the box is not fixed-size. What I would like to have is:
1. The input box should accommodate the whole text(not fixed -size).

2. the horizontal scroll bar of IE will not be shown.

Comment: the box would have to change it's size when more text is entered, right?
take a look at that http://markos.gaivo.net/examples/growtextarea/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Setting `overflow: visible` should achieve the effect you are describing (assuming you do want the text field to grow to accommodate its content.

If you want the default behavior, set `overflow: hidden` on the text field.

Setting `overflow: auto` can cause a horizontal scrollbar in IE when the content size exceeds the field width.

Comment: Please don't post the same answer multiple times. If you see questions that are duplicate, flag them as such.